# Out of Stock Product By Attributes

Tags: magento2, attributes

I have website related to Hair Wigs & i am using Magento2 & Configurable Product

There are product with Size and Color attributes... now i added quantity for Products ..say 20 ... and size and color products are more then main product ...say 30 items

Hair Wigs >> Normal Color & Normal Size >> $10 Price.... 20 Quantity

Hair Wigs >> Black Color & Size 14 >> $30 Price.... 30 Quantity

Now, what happen is
where my main product quantity is 20 and all sold out ... my product HAIR WIGS ..shows SOLD OUT...but i still have stock available with size and color which i have 30 quantity.

I want to show my products show IN STOCK where it is available with size and color.

Please help!